# App builds on physical device, but not emulator (No such module)

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication, cocoapods

My project will build on a physical device but not on an emulator. Building on an emulator says there's no such module. I've installed all necessary pods, but can't access them when trying to build on emulator. Intellisense will not pick it up.

[image]

Although, I have most definitely installed and updated the pod multiple times and even tried to use an outdated version with no luck

[image]

I've tried to delete and deintegrate pods, delete DerivedData, delete .xcworkspace file, clean build folder. I can't seem to get it to build on emulator because there is 'No such module'.

iOS deployment target is 13.2, while the emulator is running the latest version (14.2)

**Update:** This seems to happen with any pod I install... Stripe, GoogleMaps, etc..

Downloading and importing the Firebase framework directly into the project by dragging and dropping the required folders seems to get rid of the Firebase errors, but still the other modules do not work: Stripe, GoogleMaps, etc..

Comment: That's weird. Can you edit your question and mention the Xcode and simulator version you've tried? Have you tried a different simulator? If for example your simulator is iOS13, then I'd try iOS14 & iOS12 and also try iOS13 of a different simulator. Additionally I might  trying creating a dummy project and import FirebaseAuth to see if I can reproduce it in a smaller setup.

Comment: I've edited my question. I don't believe it is linked to Firebase's dependencies. I've discovered that it can happen with any 3rd party pod. I've tried to create a new project and add different pods, but I still get the same result no matter which pod/s I install.

Comment: While you say it builds on a physical device, do you have any code that's being used from the pods? Was this working before? Or you just got access to this project or something?

Comment: This project has been on my computer for quite some time. I hadn't opened the project or Xcode for 3 months, but after updating from xcode 11 to 12 is when it started happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hours of searching, I've discovered that `Build Active Architecture Only` in the build settings was set to Yes by default. Simply setting it to No allowed it to build.

Comment: This didn't fix the problem for me :-/ Only my physical device allows me to build.
In my case after building for emulator xCode is telling me:
"Module 'FirebaseFirestore' not found. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the appropriate pods installed?

Comment: Yes I do. It's really confusing, I am happy that it works for my physical devices. But it would also be nice to try my app for iPads and different formats. :-/ Are you using Cordova or program for iOS native?

Comment: No I'm not using Cordova. My app is is separately written for each operating system.

Comment: this fix doesn't works for me, too.